Why does my reconstruced image appears darker than the original?
I am trying build an autoencoder which would encode the image into latent space and then decode it back to the original image without any changes. I am mainly trying to implement this paperUniversal Style Transfer via Feature Transforms
The encoder block is a pretrained vgg19 relu4_1 output layer and decoder is the inverse of the encoder with maxpooling replaced with upsample layer. I also used tanh after the last layer.
This is the original image

This is my trained decoders output

As you can see the the model was able to capture the feature quite well but the whole image appears dark and have some little artifacts. I have tried changing batch size, changing learning rate or even removing the tanh layer. But nothing seems to work and training the model for more epoch does not help either. I just do not know what is wrong. One thing to mention is that if I increase batch size to 32 or 64 from my current 4 small artifacts mostly go away but the image still looks dark.
Any help would appreciated

Personally, I've found that when a CNN model becomes too "narrow", or restricted in the middle (many channels with small height and width) it can be hard for the network to recreate the original image without artifacts. If possible, try removing a few layers from your model to keep it "wider" near the middle.
